# how to set landscape orientation in particular activity?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am showing graph in my activity using a graphview. Now, I need to set the orientation of activity according to user's rotation. Means, if user will hold mobile horizontally, activity should set its orientation as "landscape" and same for vertical i.e. "portrait". It should not be depends on mobile settings rotation. I just want this for my graph activity only.

here is screen short you can easily understand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7q51.png)

Comment: @SunishaSindhu no its not working

Comment: The orientation will be set permanently on compile time if you declare it in the manifest. If you set it to portrait, the activity will always be in portrait. If you check out my answer, you will see that it works on runtime.

Comment: no i haven't added any orientation in my manifest.

Comment: Is there you added orientation in application tag (in ur manifest)

Comment: @Tabishkhan have you tried my answer?

Comment: yes i tried it but i don't want it as a permanently. its should be depends on users requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To lock your Activity during runtime, you can use

```
// lock orientation to landscape
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

All you need now is to determine the current orientation, and pass it to keep it locked that way.

First, add these imports:

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
```

Then you can add this to your Activitys *onCreate()*:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // lock the current device orientation    
    int currentOrientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION‌​_PORTRAIT);
    }
    else{
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION‌​_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    // ... rest of your code 

}
```

See [ActivityInfo documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html) for the other orientation configurations.

Comment: this msg are showing after added your code, cannot resolve symbol 'SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT'

Comment: see the code
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);      int currentOrientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        else{
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }

Comment: ah i see, you added too much. The fist mention of setRequestedOrientation was only explanatory. You only need to add the last codeblock i postet to your onCreate(). I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working now. but why after implement this code my application working slow like it hang. is there any solution or reason why is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Open the AndroidManifest.xml and add the following to the activity's attribute `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` e.g.

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: its open direct landscape i do not want like that its should be depends on users.

Comment: You asked `how to set landscape orientation in particular activity?` but you also want to `set the orientation of activity according to user's rotation`. Pick one of those

Comment: He didn't specify it to landscape. He asked how to set it to landscape OR portrait, at runtime.

Comment: The title clearly says `set landscape orientation in particular activity`. And `"according to user's rotation"` is achievable by just turning on automatic screen rotation on the device self. I don't see the the term `runtime` anywhere. So the title is misleading or the description is unclear.

Comment: `if user will hold mobile horizontally, activity should set its orientation as "landscape" and same for vertical i.e. "portrait". It should not be depends on mobile settings rotation.`. If the user is in portrait, the device should stay in portrait and ignore rotation.

Comment: i have mentioned it in my question.   if user will hold mobile horizontally, activity should set its orientation as "landscape" and same for vertical i.e. "portrait". It should not be depends on mobile settings rotation either rotation on or off it doesn't matter.

Comment: Isn't that what this code does?  `if user will hold mobile horizontally, activity should set its orientation as "landscape"`, check. `same for vertical i.e. "portrait"`, check.

Comment: No, with your code, the activity will always be landscape, never protrait.

Comment: What is the difference with just turning automatic screen orientation on?

Comment: The app itself can be viewed in orientation and portrait mode. So automatic orientation is turned on. But if the user enters the graph activity, the app should be locked to the current orientation. If the user enters in portrait, the app should stay in portrait, if the user enters in landscape, the app should stay in landscape. if the user navigates back, the app should be able to rotate again.

Comment: Well that description makes it more clear than the description posted by the OP. Two users have failed to understand the question because the title just says `how to set landscape orientation in particular activity?` and the OP did not mention "lock the screen orientation based on the **entered** orientation". Entered was the keyword here

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file add the following code which Activity you need to show as landscape,

```
        <activity android:name=".activity name of yours"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        </activity>
```

or

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```